# design time anomaly in window builder and swing

Tags: java, swing, gui-designer, windowbuilder

Im experimenting with window builder for eclipse and Swing.

I created a demo calculator project with a custom JPanel

```
DigitBoardView extends JPanel
```

and assigned the keys using a for loop

```
String[] digits = {"1", ...} 
for(String digit : digits){
 JButton digButton = new JButton(digit);
 add(digButton);
}
```

1st problem - **DigitBoardView**  designer doesn't show it, 
though FAQ says it will not generate and show runtime dependant GUI
in design time (which is OK), nothing here is runtime dependant.
Even if I iterate  over the digits with an explicitly known at compile time
`for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)` loop designer doesn't edge

2nd problem - **JFrame** designer does show it!
If I set the content pane of a JFrame to be new DigitBoardView
it will be shown in design time...

Why so strange? 
Is it bug?

Should I bypass it by flattening the loop?
Isn't it extremely ugly?
Defeats the purpose of not repeating myself principle?

Comment: Where do you have the JButton creation code that you have shown above?

Comment: right in the ctor of my DigitBoardView (JPanel extension)

Answer (score 3):

Although it's tangential to the designer issue, you might like to examine [`KeyPadPanel`](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/keypad-panel), which uses  [actions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) and [key bindings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) to implement a simple numeric keypad having a simple `GridLayout`.

Comment: JPanel designer still ignores the for loop in your example, but still a great example although, thanks

Comment: I try to limit my use of a designer to the odd nested panel that is hard to maintain any other way.